# Cannot escape single perentheses in JavaScript RegExp with dynamic input

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code that I cannot seem to get to work. The code performs a string match using RegExp and has a dynamic input based on what the user has typed. However when entering a single ( I receive an error.

Firstly, I have a function to escape the user's input, that is as follows.

```
String.prototype.regExpEscape = function() {
    return this.replace(/([-()\[\]{}+?*.$\^|,:#<!\\])/g, '\\\$1');
};
```

Along with the following match code:

```
text.match(search.regExpEscape(),'i');
```

If I log the output of the regExpEscape function, I see the following:

```
// Input
Test (

// Output
Test \(
```

So it looks like that is working correctly. However I receive: `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(Test ()/: Unterminated group` in Chrome's console.

Interestingly, the function works correctly and produces no errors when running in Karma unit tests using PhantomJS.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What commands do you run to produce the error - I can not reproduce in chrome console

Comment: The error occurs when using the "text.match..." example in the question. If I manually enter the escaped string into the command it works fine, but fails when using the String.regExpEscape() method.

Comment: for what value of text? I ran all this in chrome console, and appears to work - perhaps the error lies in the part not posted, if you post full sample it might be reproducible.

Comment: I'll reproduce in a jsfiddle and share that, but the specific values I had were "Alumina (AL1100)" for text and "Alumina (" for search.

Comment: still works for me: http://imgur.com/ZlRoLZq

Comment: Ok, thank you for taking the time to check and also the screen grab, I'll try and reproduce an example and share, but this suggests something else is contributing to the error.

Comment: Confirming that this works fine for me in Chrome. Could you post your exact code?